# Parameterattribute default value (C# cmdlet) in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm designing a cmdlet using plain C#. Is it possible to define a default value for a parameter?

Script cmdlet:

```
[Parameter] [string] $ParameterName = "defaultValue"
```

Which is the equivalent for C#?

```
[Parameter]
public string ParameterName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With auto-implemented properties, you can't.
You will need to create the actual getter and setter.

Something like this:

```
private string _ParameterName = "defaultvalue";

[Parameter]
public string ParameterName 
{
     get
     {
          return _ParameterName ;
     }
     set
     {
         _ParameterName  = value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it was too obvious... I could do it with auto-implemented too, just setting them in the constructor.

Comment: yes sure why not...i answered in the context of the example you showed in question

Answer (score 9):

Since C# 6.0 has been released:

```
[Parameter]
public string ParameterName { get; set; } = "defaultValue";
```